# How to prevent this error ? Vcl.Forms.hpp(925): E2316 'FMenu' is not a member of 'TCustomForm'

Tags: c++builder, vcl

My project started to throw that error suddenly even though i dont use **FMenu**. I created a new empty project and tried to build it but got the same error. I didn't even add anything to the form just created new project and tried to build. I am using **classic borland compiler** on the project options btw.

Interesting side is that error coming from a library file **Vcl.Forms.hpp**. I dont know what to do. Here is the line that error navigated me when i click on it.

In Vcl.Forms.hpp Line 925;

```
__property Vcl::Menus::TMainMenu* Menu = {read=FMenu, write=SetMenu, stored=IsForm};
```

Comment: My bet is that You most likely messed up some VCL header file while debugging ... If the case reinstalling borland should help. To be sure without reinstalling you could try to compile on different machine if you have access to some with borland installed. Another (unlikely but not impossible) option is that Windows messed with the compiler again (there where few updates in past that required a fix for some borland IDEs maybe MS created something new to make our life more miserable). Hope that by new project you mean new project and not using old project and clearing stuff ...

Comment: Thanks @Spektre . I figured out the problem. There was a line disappeared in Vcl.Forms.hpp file that i dont know how. The line was 
Vcl::Menus::TMainMenu* FMenu;
I compared my vcl.forms file with another vcl.form from another computer. And mine was missing the line.

Comment: While debugging (breakpoint,traceing,codegueard or even crash) the debugger often opens VCL header/source in the IDE where the problem occurred (because of passing NULL pointer or whatever cause from your side of code) and if you not careful you could hit a key and save the whole stuff accidentally with your edit later on ...